# Gnuplot: can I make x axis stretch at some data points?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

[image]I have vector of time points which will be represented at x axis.
some of these time points occur at certain sign and other time points occur at different sign.
I want to scale x to y  for first sign as x=1:y=1 .
I want to scale x to y  for second sign as x=2:y=1
So that I will have one graph with x axis stretched at some points" x unit = double space e.g. 2 cm for 1 hour" and contracted at other points   "x unit= single space e.g. 1 cm for 1 hour"
I have array with same index as time array which has 1 for single space time points and 2 for double space time points.
can I plot this in gnuplot?
UPDATE:
if it is not possible in gnuplot ,is there any other library which can draw points with control of axis scale per point?"one array for axis scale per point and another for axis data??"
UPDATE:
data points:100 50 70 130 40 20 30 50 88 93
points width:1  1  1  2   2  2   2  1  1  1
time ticks  : 1   2  3  4  5   6   7  8  9  10
these time ticks should be on x axis but with space between 1 2 3 as 1 unit e.g. 1 cm and space between 4 5 6 7 as 2 units e.g. 2 cm then between 8 9 10 as 1 unit
the data points will be 1000000 with random 1 and 2 units portions.
I do not know how to draw their graph.

Comment: I have difficulties to understand what you mean. What do you mean with sign? Can you please show some example data and make a sketch what you would like to have?

Comment: Ok. what should be the space between 3 & 4 and 7 & 8 ? 1 cm or 2 cm?

Comment: between 3 and 4 it will be 2 and between 7 and 8 it will be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure whether I fully understand, but here is what I think you might want.
So, you have events which are just counted from 1, ... N. These events do not occur in regular timesteps. Sometimes after 1 second, some times after 2 seconds. In order to plot this you simply have to sum up all these time differences, e.g. in a variable `t`.

**Code:**

```
### add variable stepsize for x-values
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   1  100 
 2   1   50
 3   1   70
 4   2  130
 5   2   40
 6   2   20
 7   2   30
 8   1   50
 9   1   88
10   1   93
EOD

set grid x

plot t=0 $Data u (t):(t=t+$2,$3) w lp pt 7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here is another attempt trying to understand what you mean.
That's what I understand now from your question and comments.
You have events and the distance between them are as follows:
Distance between 1,2,3 should be 1, between 3,4,5,6,7 should be 2, between 7,8,9,10 should be 1.

```
# event    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
# distance   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1
```

**Code:** (you can skip the second line of the plot command. It's just to show event number)

```
### add variable stepsize for x-values
reset session

$Data <<EOD 
 1   1  100
 2   1   50
 3   1   70
 4   2  130
 5   2   40
 6   2   20
 7   2   30
 8   1   50
 9   1   88
10   1   93
EOD

set grid x
set offsets 0,1,0,0

plot t=0 $Data u (t=t+$2):3 w lp pt 7 notitle, \
     t=0 ''    u (t=t+$2):3:1 w labels offset 0,1 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: no ,both events occur at same time step but i need to make scale of this time step different .what I imagine is that if there is variable for pixels for time step e.g. p=100 pixels. I need to multiply this p by 1 to draw time step with 100 pixels,then multiply p by 2 to draw another step by 200 pixels.I need this because afterwards I will draw line at some lows of graph ,and calculate its slope.so the expansion of some parts of x scale will be effective in calculation of slope.

Comment: here your time scale is the same but some points happens in 1  or 2 sec.what i need is both events happening at 1 second but this 1 second is drawn longer in case of 2 than in case of 1

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear to me what you mean. For example, event 3 happens at time 3 with duration 1, so you want the point plotted at 3+1=4? Event 7 happens at time 7 with duration 2, so point plotted at 7+2=9? And event 8 happens at time 8 with duration 1, so point plotted at 8+1=9 as well? Please provide a complete and clear sketch of all of your 10 example data points given above how you want them to be drawn.

Comment: i changed picture to view the numbers

Comment: ok, so these are the distances you see in my second plot. What do you want to do with the values of the datapoints? Plot as y-value or just all on the same level as in your sketch? I still don't understand your final goal.

Comment: I think the only way is to make array of labels of values having the values 123456789 and make another array of values which are used on x axis 12345678910111213 where label 4 is at 5 on x axis and label 7 is at 10 on x axis

Comment: That's what the second code is doing. Label 4 at x-axis 5, ok. But why should label 7 be at 10 (and not 11)? You were basically telling that the distances are in the second column, right? Can you please exactly describe what you want to have?

Comment: so, what's wrong with my second graph? Isn't this what you were asking for?